# Laravel 5.4 and Semantic UI

Tags: laravel, semantic-ui

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Semantic 2.2.7. Here is my mix

```
mix.combine(['resources/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'resources/libs/semantic/dist/semantic.js'], 'public/js/vendor.js')
.combine(['resources/libs/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css', 'resources/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'], 'public/css/vendor.css')
.js('resources/assets/js/scripts/login.validator.js', 'public/js/scripts.js')
.less('resources/assets/less/style.less', 'public/css');
```

I get my js libraries combined well in vendor.js. If i followup the login example from [link](http://semantic-ui.com/examples/login.html), i am getting the error as follows.

Note: I checked the using view source and i could map the forms.js code into the vendor.js file.[image]

Any solutions i need to set in laravel?

Also, why my scripts.js file 10343 lines whereas my login.validator.js is only 34 lines

Comment: The problem is jQuery is getting added to js file generated if i use mix.js. I tested the js file individually mapped and its working.

Comment: try to load jQuery and other third party libraries from other sources like Google APIs and not mix them in the final output

Comment: It works in that case. The issue is when i run mix.js() laravel adds jQuery & Sizzle.js again. No idea how to avoid jquery readdition while running mix.js

Answer (score 1):

You have to set jQuery as `global`. Webpack loads module only when it needs, so you have to use `autoload()` to make it works everywhere.

```
mix.autoload({
   jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use webpack [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) to avoid jquery readdition, You can add the setting in webpack.mix.js file, see Laravel mix [custom webpack configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#custom-webpack-configuration).

example (not tested)

webpack.mix.js

```
...
...
mix.webpackConfig({
    entry: {
        vendor: ["jquery", "other-lib"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
           name: 'vendor'
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this package out. It works for me.
https://github.com/Maxlab/laravel-vue-semantic-ui